# Tweak grub2 loader

Tags: ubuntu, windows, grub2

I just dual booted with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. I notice that when Windows goes to Hibernation mode, when I get out of hiberation mode and get to the GRUB loader, and choose Windows 7 it freezes. Is there any kind of edit(s) I can make to the `/etc/default/grub` file that will prevent it from freezing after I choose Windows?

EDIT: This tends to also happen when I am in Ubuntu and decide to restart and choose Windows. Any suggestions?

Comment: `grubloader.conf`? Didn't you mean `/etc/default/grub`?

Comment: Yes sorry, i didnt know the exact name of the config file..